# QML - Passing Javascript associative array to C++

Tags: javascript, c++, arrays, qml, qt-quick

In my app I have a class which registered as singleton for `QML`. My purpose is collecting values in `QML` as associative array and passing this array to `C++`. This is the simplified version of the class:

```cpp
class Config : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
private:
  Config(QObject *parent = 0);
public:
  static Config *instance();
  ~Config();
  Q_INVOKABLE void sendValue (const QVariantMap &map) {
    qWarning() << map.size();
  }
}
```

and here I register an instance of the class as singleton:

```cpp
qmlRegisterSingletonType<Config>("myNS", 1, 0, "Config", config_singletontype_provider);
```

In some place in QML file I try to pass javascript array back to c++;

```js
function sendValue() {
  var arr = [];
  arr["key"] = "value";
  Config.sendValue(arr);      
}
```

But nothing passed. The `map.size()` in `C++` returns 0. May be I need some additional conversion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I answer to my own question )
The documentation is not so clear but, as I understand, `Qt` converts JS array to `QVariantList` and **JS object** to `QVariantMap`
So in my case I just need to create an object, not array:

```js
var arr = {};
```